# Why is the Ar-40 nucleus lighter than Ca-40?

Tags: nuclear-physics

I'm doing some problems on decay of K-40 with some students, and I'm baffled by the numbers I'm finding. I expected there to be a much greater mass defect for beta-minus decay than for beta-plus, and I'm finding the opposite. In beta-minus emission, we have a Ca-40 nucleus produced, while in beta-positive, we have a Ar-40. Since the Ar-40 is more neutron-heavy, I would expect it to be heavier, not lighter.

I also calculate the mass defect for beta-minus decay as 8.514e-4 u, which works out to about 0.79 MeV, and that's much less than the 1.3 MeV I read about online. I'm using the following values of masses, taken from CRC tables:
K-40: 39.9640 u
Ca-40: 39.9626 u
Ar-40: 39.9624 u
e: 5.4858e-4 u

I'm wondering if anyone either sees my mistake, my incorrect value, or has a relatively simple explanation. Thanks!

---

Edit: I may have made a more fundamental error. I was assuming the masses I found were for the nuclei alone, but if they’re atomic masses, the extra electron that must be added or removed to make the daughter atom neutral might be the source of my error. Would anyone corroborate?

Answer (score 4):

Ca40 is a doubly magic nucleus, so it has a higher average binding energy per nucleon (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(physics) )

Comment: Thanks; that’s good to remember!